# How to avoid that Diazo change "#" links in Plone?

Tags: plone, diazo

I'm using Diazo with Plone 4. In one of the HTML template files I wrote a link pointing the same page, like this:

```
    <a href="#">foo</a>
```

But it is rendered as:

```
    <a href="/mysite/++theme++my.theme/">foo</a>
```

How I can avoid that Diazo changes the original template code or there is a specific mechanism to point the same page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a bug in plone.app.theming, though. The relative-to-absolute parser should ignore anchor links.

Comment: I think is a bug too. I will publish code replicating the bug. Now I fixed it in my application using javascript.

Answer (score 2):

The "Diazo theme" control panel on Plone has an option called "Absolute path prefix" (on "Advanced settings" tab), which defines that magic. Alternatively, you could try to define a rule, which replaces "#"-links with the pre-defined $path-variable.

See [plone.app.theming](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.theming) for more information about the settings on "Advanced tab" or pre-defined variables.

Comment: I can't use the global "Absolute path prefix" because the object pointed by "#" is relative to the page path. So different pages will need different path prefix. Also, I'm using relative URLs in the theme, so I can't change the path prefix.

Comment: There is another thing: the "#" is replaced by "/mysite/++theme++my.theme" not by "/++theme++my.theme" that is the absolute path prefix.

Comment: /mysite/ is added by plone.app.theming and it's ok. Otherwise, I side with you and Martin that this really is a bug in diazo compiler. It uses Python's urlparse.urljoin to apply absolute path prefix for every url. I think, there should be a wrapper around urljoin to skip joins for urls beginning with '#'.

Comment: I tried to compose a test and a patch for this: https://github.com/plone/diazo/pull/3